# Series with $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ being $+$ and $-\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf, conditional-convergence

Do you have an example of a series whose partial sums' $\lim \sup = \infty$ and whose partial sums' $\lim \inf = -\infty$  ?

I feel like it's like repeatingly adding a whole bunch of positive terms one time then substracting an even bigger whole bunch of negative terms, isn't that a way to get it ?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach (if you mean alternating positive and negative with increasing absolute values). Where did this question come from?

Comment: A series has a value (or diverges), not lim sups or lim infs. Are you asing about the sequence of partial sums of a series?

Comment: It came after a read the proof of the Riemann theorem (a conditionally converging series can be rearranged such as its $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ can be any value on the extended real line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_{n}= n (-1)^{n}$ and the series be $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (f_{k}-f_{k-1})=f_n$.